# How to use cmd + V to paste into a Ubuntu VM in Parallels?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, parallels-desktop, copy-paste

I *think* that I have the proper settings that should allow me to use <kbd>Command</kbd>  <kbd>V</kbd> to paste into my Parallels Ubuntu command line:

[image]

and

[image]

But when I try to paste into the command line using <kbd>Command</kbd>  <kbd>V</kbd> nothing happens.  If type that twice in a row `^V` appears in the command line, but not the text in my clipboard.  How can I get <kbd>Command</kbd>  <kbd>V</kbd> working to paste?

Comment: The *caret* "^" and the letter is a symbol that you get when when you press *Ctrl*, not *Command*  and letter combination. Do you have it remapped or are you using an Apple keyboard?

Comment: I'm using an Apple Keyboard

Comment: have you tried to paste using `ctrl + v`?

Comment: Yes.  I'd rather not have to use `ctrl`, but it didn't work either way.

Comment: Did you install the Parallels Tools properly?

Answer (score 6):

Annoying problem, but copy/paste is different in Linux terminal:

Cut - Ctrl + Shift + X.

Copy - Ctrl + Shift + C.

Paste - Ctrl + Shift + V.

Hope this helps.

see: https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-cut-copy-and-paste-in-the-terminal-in-ubuntu

Comment: Might be not worth argueing about something which isn't very clear based on the question. The OP may or may not know Ubuntu key bindings, and we currently can only guess why they can't paste.